# Alignment of header and column in custom styled glossary

Tags: longtable, glossaries, alignment

I am a novice at LaTeX and I have currently a little issue with glossary formating.

Since none of the predefined styles were convenient for me I have created my own style using the vast documentation for the package. However I can't resolve what is causing a slight off-center alignment in the first column. The rest of the glossary is absolutely OK. Only the first column behaves like all entries below the header had some kind of invisible spacer from the left side what is well visible when I set it to be left-justified.

I am pretty sure it is some kind of elemantary and obvious mistake. I just browsed throughtout all forums and documentations and I can't make it work. Maybe it causes the math-mode and the glossary don't like maths??? IDK

I'd be delighted for any help.

I haven't pasted there all code related to glossary because I am using more glossaries in my document (for acronyms and so) which work perfectly though. So I presume the problem is hidden somewhere in this code:

```
\usepackage[toc,acronyms,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
...
\newglossarystyle{long333col}{
\renewenvironment{theglossary}
{\begin{longtable}{|c|c|p{\glsdescwidth}|}}
{\end{longtable}}

% Table's header:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
\bfseries Symbol & \bfseries Notation & \bfseries Brief description
\\\endhead\hline\rule{0pt}{6mm}}

% No heading between groups:
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}

% Entries displayed in a row:
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
\glsentryitem{##1}
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}}
& \glossentryname{##1}
& \glossentrydesc{##1}
\tabularnewline\rule{0pt}{6mm}
}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
}
```

[image]

There is also example of the glossary entry:

```
\newglossaryentry{zeta}
{
name={damping ratio},
symbol={$\zeta$},
description={dimensionless parameter describing system damping and oscillations decay}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... for future generations ...

After many many hours of searching, I haven't found out why this stylistic typo is occuring. However, I found a simple way in one code how to solve it. Just add extra line at the beginning of each entry with negative length parameter to (partially) delete it:

```
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
\tabularnewline[-3mm]
\glsentryitem{##1}
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}}
& \glossentryname{##1}
& \glossentrydesc{##1}
\tabularnewline
}}
```

This is the result:
[image]